# Superfish Menu Wont Close

Tags: drupal

Im working with the Omega theme in Drupal 7 and I have added a SuperFish Menu block to one of my regions. The menu has 5 different links and Ive set it to vertical are set in the SuperFish section, but the menu just stays open on the page (regardless of browser).

All of the links function as they should, but the menu isnt closed when the page loads and stays open all of the time. All of my JS paths are correct!

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that some of your CSS is overriding the display or visibility attributes that hides the superfish menu.

Comment: Why don't you give us the details of how that helped you - what was overriding what?